# Inserting a quote as an exhibit in LyX

Tags: lyx, quoting

I would like to insert a quote into the LyX document that stands out from the rest of the text and is displayed as a display formula would be (on a separate line with space around it).  For example:

```
Hello, this is some random text that I have. Hello, this is some random 
text that I have also. Hello, this is some random text that I have again. 
Hello, this is some random text that I have. Hello, this is some random 
text that I have also. Hello, this is some random text that I have again. 

    Some famous quote

Hello, this is some random text that I have. Hello, this is some random 
text that I have also. Hello, this is some random text that I have again. 
Hello, this is some random text that I have. Hello, this is some random 
text that I have also. Hello, this is some random text that I have again.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use the `Quotation` layout for that specific paragraph (from the top-left drop-down menu). This will place the paragraph inside a `quotation` environment, specifically used to highlight some piece of text:

[image]

Comment: How do you open the "Latex Source" panel? Can you edit the TeX code directly there?

Comment: @deps_stats: View > Code Preview Pane. No, you can't edit content there the way you would think of as when using an editor.

Answer (score 0):

The way to do this is through the `csquotes` package. Here is a link with detailed instructions and an example:

https://www.sharelatex.com/learn/Typesetting_quotations

Comment: Is there some reason you don't want to use the built-in "Quote" and "Quotation" constructs from the format menu? Apologies if I'm not using the right terminology; I'm not a LyX user myself.

Comment: nope, just didn't know about it! thanks for pointing it out